# Radio onClick change

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I need help with this code. Right now, it does `reload` every time if there are some changes in the form. I want it to `reload` / `change` only when a certain radio button is clicked.
I've tried putting `onChange` or `onClick` function to the radios but that didn't work. I don't know what to do. Also, I need those radios to store which one is selected.

Code:

```php
<?php
session_start();
$radio = "";

if(isset($_POST['radio'])){
    $_SESSION['radio'] = $_POST['radio'];
}

if(isset($_SESSION['radio'])){
    $radio = $_SESSION['radio'];
}
?>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>html template</title>
  <meta name="description" content="html template">
  <meta name="author" content="dp">

</head>

<body>
    <form class="sellForm" action="" method="post" onchange="this.submit()">
        <table>
        <input <?php if ($radio=='intern'){ echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> type="radio" id="internSale" name="radio" value="intern" checked><label class="sellRadio" for="internSale">Intern</label>
        <input <?php if ($radio=='adaptee'){ echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> type="radio" id="adapteeSale" name="radio" value="adaptee"><label class="sellRadio" for="adapteeSale">Adaptee</label>
        <tr <?php if ($radio=='intern'){ echo 'style="display: none;"';}?>><td><label style="font-weight: bold;">Adaptee ID:</label></td><td><input type="number" placeholder="210301001"></td></tr>
        <tr <?php if ($radio=='intern'){ echo 'style="display: none;"';}?>><td><label style="font-weight: bold;">Customer:</label></td><td><input type="number" placeholder="730477541"></td></tr>

        <tr><td><label style="font-weight: bold;">Item/s:</label></td><td><select name="selectItems" class="positionSelect" id="mySelect">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="1">option1</option>
            <option value="2">option2</option>
            <option value="3">option3</option>
            <option value="4">option4</option>
        </select></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label style="font-weight: bold;">Price:</label></td><td><input type="float" placeholder="170.00">,-</td></tr>
        <tr><td><label style="font-weight: bold;">Note:</label></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="note here"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="submit"></td></tr>  
    </table>
    </form>
    <?php echo $radio;?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `onchange="this.submit()"` on form, so what do you expect? Use i.e. jQuery to handle listeners on given selectors by id, class, or whatever else.

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
<form class="sellForm" action="" method="post" onchange="this.submit()">
```

to:

```
<form id="sellForm" action="" method="post" >
```

and add this js:

```
function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("sellForm").submit();
}
```

and finally add a onclick event to the radio button you want to use as trigger and check if the button is checked ( you should add that to myFunction())

Answer (score 0):

you need to add event `change` listener to the radios and remove `onchange="this.submit()"`

jQuery

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
    this.parentElement.submit(); // go to <form> then submit
});
```

vanilla JS

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]').forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('change', function() {
    this.parentElement.submit(); // go to <form> then submit
  })
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```html
<form name="quiz" id="quizable">
<table id="q_table">
<tr><td>Banana</td><td><input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1_1" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Apple</td><td><input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1_2" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Coconut</td><td><input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1_3" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Cherry</td><td><input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1_4" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

[Radio onClick change](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.direct.onlineservice)

Comment: The answer will be more useful if you explain better what you mean with your code. Also, avoid using links not related to the question.